# How to force children to have a certain attribute

Tags: reactjs, typescript

As the title said, I have a react FC like this:

```
const Test = (props: { 
    children: React.ReactElement<{ slot: "content" }> 
}) => {
    return <></>
}
```

now, pass a child without slot attribute, there are not any ts error

```
const test = (
    <Test>
        <span>some content</span>
    </Test>
)
```

I know that span tag will be infered as JSX.Element, but is there any way for me to receive a ts error stating that span does not have slot attribute

Comment: I don't think this is possible.. how about wrapping `span` with a react element and using it? [example code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/pedantic-bouman-43xyd3?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx%3A6%2C57)

Comment: yeah, there is no way to make it, react documentation has said that children is an opaque data structure

Comment: "_is there any way for me to receive a ts error stating that span does not have slot attribute?_": [Yes](https://tsplay.dev/NlzVeW), but the built-in JSX types don't offer a way to satisfy the constraint without a type assertion at each usage site.

Comment: Technically this is possible. but it would require overriding the React namespace, and updating the HTML element type to require a specific attribute. I wouldn't recommend this. Instead, can you explain your use case better? I suspect theres a different way to do what you are trying to do

Comment: Extra illustrate of sample code：The Test tag is a  web-components and be imported by like `import "./components/test.js"`. For obtaining ts type hinting I has defined `JSX.IntrinsicElements` in test.d.ts, I could hint the props type easily, additional I want to hint user that it have to provide a slot...   
But there seems no way to make it, now I have to embed children into a react component to achieve my goal.

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not possible:
["The JSX result type"](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsx.html#the-jsx-result-type):

> By default the result of a JSX expression is typed as `any`. You can customize the type by specifying the `JSX.Element` interface. However, it is not possible to retrieve type information about the element, attributes or children of the JSX from this interface. It is a black box.

The JSX code (like `<span>some content</span>`) is always interpreted as type `JSX.Element` (as you said).

`JSX.Element` is defined as:

```js
declare global {
    namespace JSX {
        interface Element extends React.ReactElement<any, any> {}
    }
}
```

[`any`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any) is by definition assignable to any type (and any type can be assigned to it).

So there is no way to restrict anything inside your component, because there is no information about what is coming in, it is just `any`.

### Why is it a problem ?

Instead of restricting the type that is coming in, you *would* have to overwrite the `JSX.Element` type that is created, in some way like *(but that doesn't work either)*:

```js
declare global {
    namespace JSX {
        interface Element<K, V> extends React.ReactElement<K, V> {} // <-- doesn't work
    }
}
```

... so that `K` and `V` are inferred from the JSX code.

But TypeScript can not infer the types from JSX code.

TS on its own doesn't even know what the JSX code should be compiled to,
you have to configure TS so that it compiles to creating React elements (which is usually pre-defined already). But you
could also have JSX code be compiled to something completely different, or not at all (i.e. just pass the JSX code through unchanged).
(E.g. tsconfig.json options [`jsx`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#jsx) or [`jsxFactory`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#jsxFactory))

Also, TS scans the source code and applies/infers all the types,
and then creates the JS code (without the types) and converts the JSX to JS.

Now, I suppose that it would be technically possible to develop a system to infer types from JSX code,
but it would be quite a lot of effort. E.g.:

- Convert in 2 steps internally, first the JSX to TS before type checking, and then the TS to JS
- Define a syntax for the user to flexibly define how JSX code should be mapped to a function definition (or even other JS code)
- The user or TS have to make sure the JSX to JS function matches the JSX to JS type definition.
  E.g. how to define that the JSX attributes `key` and `children` are special ?